# How do I capitalize first character after a special character?

Tags: substitute

I want to convert `"abc_def_ghi ( abc_def_ghi )"` to `"abc_def_ghi ( abcDefGhi )"`.

Note: If I visually select the string within (), the below command changes whole line instead of the selected text.

```
:'<,'>s/_./\U\0/g |'<,'>s/_//g
```

Fix: Visual select the text then `:'<,'>s/\%V_./\U\0/g |'<,'>s/\%V_//g`
`\%V` will only match the visual selection.

Comment: `:%s/\%((.*\)\@<=_\(\a\)/\u\1/g`

Comment: It's working. Please post your comment as Answer. Better with some explaintions about the command. Thanks!

Comment: If you'd like to perform this kind of substitution interactively from Normal mode, consider plugin vim-abolish (https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish#coercion) which has a command to coerce to camelCase, `crc`, and similar commands for other cases.

Comment: @lcd047 please post an answer!

Comment: Update, that works if there are multiple groups of parens on the same line: `:%s/\%(([^()]\{-}\)\@<=_\(\a\)\ze\@=.\{-})/\u\1/g`.  Posting as an answer is left as an exercise to the reader. :p